# Possibly lost some changes via git

Tags: git

The other day I was trying to push some changes to the remote server.

I kept getting an error so I looked to see what branch I was on.

I saw that I was un an undefined branch locally, which was really freaking weird so I checked out master and then was able to push.

Just checked out the merge and none of my changes were there. They aren't here locally. 10+ hours of work, and I can't find it anywhere.

I did a gitk and I don't see any of my changes. I do see a merge of master that looks like this:

```
Author: Sara Chipps <sarajchipps@Sara-Chippss-MacBook-Pro.local>  2012-01-04 13:48:20
Committer: Sara Chipps <sarajchipps@Sara-Chippss-MacBook-Pro.local>  2012-01-04 13:48:20
Parent: 1a294db3a244d7aeaafbc99c986af86ce7cf17da (Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/thing/thing)
Parent: 8ed995c7a5a370333ab27485be07f6a5f647e8d4 (added subscription button to edit profile section)
Child:  0dbf7e53737c0e7ee7ab908812299c1d60ef0c46 (removed coffee icon on getting started)
Branches: master, remotes/origin/master
Follows: 
Precedes: 

    Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/thing/thing
```

I am not the only one committing to this project, I don't know how I got on an undefined branch locally. Can anyone suggest a fix? Worried about losing a lot of work.

thank you.

Comment: You can only arrive on an "undefined branch" (I assume you mean detached head?) through your own actions. You may have attempted to merge and not noticed there were conflicts.

Comment: @meagar: Merge, conflicts or not, doesn't detach HEAD. Rebase does though!

Comment: @Jefromi True. I'm used to `git pull --rebase`ing

Comment: @meagar There are somedays I wish rebase didn't exist, and then others when I'm so grateful for it.  It is definitely a mixed blessing.  If upstream has a lot of conflicting commits, it's a nightmare.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check

```
git reflog
```

That will give you a history of operations, and if your changes were checked in, they'll be in a revision somewhere in that log.

You might also look at the output from:

```
git rev-list --all --header HEAD
```

This will show a large chunk of what's in the repository. You may need to work with -n to limit, and the output is a bit confusing. Have a look at the [man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) page for git-rev-list for additional information. This will hopefully help figure out where you are.

You can also create a branch at the current location:

```
git branch my temporary
```

Then use gitk

```
gitk --all
```

to get an idea too.

Comment: omg, that found it, thanks so much. I can't mark this as the answer yet, but I will when the limit times out.

Comment: I only discovered the reflog recently after a similar situation befell me when I was using git-svn!  I thought I was doomed, three days of work in the balance, I think I just about cried when I found the revision!

Comment: That is how I felt, it was awesome to find it was still there.